Change starting pose of animation
I have model with a T-pose as rest position. I have an animation that I created by deleting the the first 1/2 of the key frames in the animation to get just want I needed. However, but cropping the animation, the rest pose of the armature in that animation is now much closer to an 'arms at their side' pose. When i retarget this animation onto the T-pose model the arms are now at close to 90 degrees away from where I need them.
I'm quite new to Blender so I need help working out what I need to do so that when I retarget the animation onto the T-pose model, the arms remain at its side where I need them.
Thanks very much?

i highly recommend providing your blend file so we see what you done, show us what animation you want by e.g. providing a yt link
